# Map Shift-Insert in Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to map Shift-Insert to paste command by adding this line in vimrc

`nnoremap <S-Insert>     "+P`

But it does not change anything.

If I put other shortcut like (`<S-I>`) it works well.

Comment: I think X is capturing it before its getting to Vim. So vim might be configured for that sequence, but it never sees it. I think there is a way to turn off these kinds of things in X, but someone else will have to chime in for that.

Comment: We need to know what operating system you're using and whether you're using console Vim or gVim.  Console Vim under *nix cannot see the Shift+Insert key combination, due to limitations in (n)curses and terminal emulation; that is, it's not Vim's fault.

Comment: I doubt he is using gvim. Key recognition is a recurrent problem with vim, unlike gvim. (I don't say this is a vim issue though. It's tied to the terminal)

Answer (score 11):

Try putting following lines in .vimrc

```
" Make shift-insert work like in Xterm
map <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
map! <S-Insert> <MiddleMouse>
```

I had the same problem and after putting this lines in .vimrc shift insert works like a charm. 
Refrence:http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/104539

Answer (score 1):

Try putting following lines in `.vimrc`

```
" Paste yanked text
map <S-Insert> <C-r>"
map! <S-Insert> <C-r>"
```